# how to unset empty arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, unset

i have an array `$mainArray` of arrays and i would like to remove / undset the arrays that vave keys with no value.

here is my array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [msg_id] => 203
        [comment] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [com_id] => 
                    )
            )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [msg_id] => 202
        [comment] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [com_id] => 196
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [com_id] => 197
                    )
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [com_id] => 
                    )
            )
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [msg_id] => 201
        [comment] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [com_id] => 198
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [com_id] => 
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

In this case i would like to look inside `comment` array arrays and see if there are any of them that have empty values. The best case scenario would be to remove the `comment` array entirely if all sub arrays are empty.

nut im of with leaving the `comment` hey there just null

this array should become:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [msg_id] => 203
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [msg_id] => 202
            [comment] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [com_id] => 196
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [com_id] => 197
                        )
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [msg_id] => 201
        )
)
```

any ideas on how to proceed?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array_map(function ($i) {
    $i['comment'] = array_filter($i['comment'], function ($c) { return $c['com_id']; });
    return array_filter($i);
}, $array);
```

Requires PHP 5.3 or higher.

Answer (score 2):

Use php's `unset()` to unset any array key/value.

More info on this link https://www.php.net/unset

in your case the code can be, (i have not tested it. but let me know if you have any problem and i can fix it)

```
function unsetCommentFromArray($mainArray) {
    foreach($mainArray as $key => $value) {
        foreach($value['comment'] as $k => $v) {
            if(empty($v['com_id'])) {
                unset($mainArray[$key]['comment'][$k]);
            }
        }   
    }
    return $mainArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`array_filter()` is what you're after. Particularly a recursive version. The following was taken from [a comment on the PHP Doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#107289):.

```
function array_filter_recursive($array, $callback = null) {
    foreach ($array as $key => & $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = array_filter_recursive($value, $callback);
        }
        else {
            if ( ! is_null($callback)) {
                if ( ! $callback($value)) {
                    unset($array[$key]);
                }
            }
            else {
                if ( ! (bool) $value) {
                    unset($array[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    unset($value);

    return $array;
}
```